# Proof: Ratio of same normals is uniform?

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, normal-distribution, projection

I am currently working through a proof that uses (without reference) the following result. I cannot find a proof to this result, and would appreciate any help.

Denote the stacked regression as $Y = X\beta + \varepsilon$, where $Y$ is a $ n \times 1$ vector, $X$ a $n \times k$ matrix, and $\beta$ a $k\times 1$ vector. Use the $||A||$ to indicate the Euclidean norm of $A$. Moreover, let $\varepsilon\sim N(0,\sigma^2I_n)$ for some $0< \sigma^2 < \infty$. Define also the projection matrix $P_X:= X(X'X)^{-1}X'$. 
Under these circumstances, it holds that ${P_X(Y-X\beta)}\big/{||P_X(Y-X\beta)||}$ is a random vector which is uniformly distributed on the unit sphere in the column space of $X$.

---

It seems clear to me that (i) $(Y-X\beta) = \varepsilon$ and thus normal, (ii) $P_X$ projects the iid entries of $\varepsilon$ into the column space of $X$, (iii) the denominator (i.e., $||P_X(Y-X\beta)||$) will the the square root of a sum of scaled $\chi^2$ variables, but I don't know how to arrive at the result/claim made.

Comment: It suffices to prove that the distribution of that ratio is invariant under rotations of the columns of $X$.

Comment: [The wiki article on the hat matrix should be of considerable help](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hat_matrix)

Comment: I think the question title is a bit misleading. You are not actually considering a ratio of two random normal variables (which also does not yield a uniform random variable).